# Kotlin lambda syntax

Tags: kotlin

In the below code, what is wrong with the second add?

```
val lambdas  = mutableListOf<()->Unit>()
lambdas.add{println("a")} // this compiles fine
lambdas.add{()->println("b")} //why can't I do this?


error: expecting a name
lambdas.add{{()->println("b")}}
```

Comment: Read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expressions-and-anonymous-functions) to learn the syntax of lambda's in kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a lambda the way you are trying to

```
val right: () -> Int = { 1 } // Convenient way to declare a lambda without parameters
val alsoRight: () -> Int = { -> 1 } // The right way to explicitly declare a lambda without parameters
val wrong: () -> Int = { () -> 1 } // The wrong way to declare a lambda without parameters
```

That line should look like this:

```
lambdas.add { -> println("b") }
```